# can't create page from template in confluence

Tags: templates, confluence

I created a page template in confluence, according to documentation, just like in this URL
https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf61/create-a-template-877187723.html

Everything went according to how documentation said, and I created and promoted my new template.

Template I made was simple (for a start) - 2 fields:
Title and description.  That's all

Then when I go to "Create page from my template, the form opens, but the "Next" button does not work.  Nothing happens when I click it.

Can anyone help ?  I am "supposed" to be the space administrator there, but .. maybe there is something else missing ??
[Create page from template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYnBO.jpg)

Comment: Did you see any error in the browser console? Also, clearing your cache might help

Comment: No, no errors.  Was clearing the cache.. did not help.
I was given a different space, for testing, and it worked there.  But then we renamed that test space to what we needed it to be named, and it stopped working again :(